# 4 tables Join and show it in Java MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have this project written in java. I want this thing show data from different table in 1 display.

Here's the java code

```java
static void showPersonality() {
    try {          
        Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM faculty JOIN teacher ON faculty.id=teacher.faculty_id JOIN department ON faculty.id=department.faculty_id JOIN course ON department.id=course.department_id");

        while (rs1.next()) {
           
            String namaFakultas = rs1.getString("faculty_name");
            String namaDosen = rs1.getString("teacher_name");
            String namaDepartemen = rs1.getString("department_name");
            String namaKursus = rs1.getString("course_name");
            System.out.println(String.format("| %s | %s | %s | %s |", namaFakultas, namaDepartemen, namaKursus, namaDosen));            
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And I also made 4 table which is faculty, department, teacher, and course

Faculty table (I inserted 1 data)

```sql
CREATE TABLE faculty(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    faculty_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Department table (I inserted 2 data in 1 faculty)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `faculty_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `faculty_id` (`faculty_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `department_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`faculty_id`) REFERENCES `faculty` (`id`)
);
```

Teacher table (I inserted 2 data in 1 faculty with each data has different department)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `teacher` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `teacher_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `faculty_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `department_id` (`department_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `teacher_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`),
  KEY `faculty_id` (`faculty_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `teacher_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`faculty_id`) REFERENCES `faculty` (`id`)
);
```

Course table (I inserted 2 data with each data has different department)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `course_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `department_id` (`department_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `course_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`)
);
```

After I execute the code, it shows 4 data

```
| Teknik | Informatika | OOP | Adi Gunawan |
| Teknik | Sistem Informasi | Basis Data | Adi Gunawan |
| Teknik | Informatika | OOP | Ani Wijaya |
| Teknik | Sistem Informasi | Basis Data | Ani Wijaya |
```

My expectation it only show 2 data with all different table except Faculty table

```
| Teknik | Informatika | OOP | Adi Gunawan |
| Teknik | Sistem Informasi | Basis Data | Ani Wijaya |
```

Is there anything wrong with my java code or maybe my database?

Comment: You have to show the records that are present on the database, the data resulting from the query and what do you expect

Comment: I've edit my data result and data expect. Maybe something wrong with my code or my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(ouput is just show an list of name, not id. you should show all of raw datalist for correct answer)

---

(guess name values of other 3 tables are unique. but name of course table are not unique.)

i think it just the data problem.

in query, after front 3 joins are executed, maybe return 2 rows.

```
| Teknik | Informatika | OOP 
| Teknik | Sistem Informasi | Basis Data
```

and look at the final results after next 4th join step(reordered output)

```
| Teknik | Informatika | OOP | Adi Gunawan |
| Teknik | Informatika | OOP | Ani Wijaya |
| Teknik | Sistem Informasi | Basis Data | Adi Gunawan |
| Teknik | Sistem Informasi | Basis Data | Ani Wijaya |
```

as you can see,
it means that each `OOP` and `Basis Data` joined with 2 rows of `course table`
so raw data expect:

```sql
# rows in course table

... OOP_id | Adi Gunawan
OOP_id | Ani Wijaya
Basis Data_id | Adi Gunawan
Basis Data_id | Ani Wijaya
```

if you want,

```
| Teknik | Informatika | OOP | Adi Gunawan |
| Teknik | Sistem Informasi | Basis Data | Ani Wijaya |
```

`on` clause of 4th join, maybe not a `department_id` column, it must another column

if `course data` have `faculty_id`, join with `faculty_id` of two tables

---

### edit.

after your comment,
i found i missed one thing.

`teacher` table have two relationship

- many to one relationship with `faculty` table.
- many to one relationship with `department` table.

so
in `on` clause after joining `teacher`, you should add condition that  `teacher`'s `department_id` = `department`'s `id` too. not just `faculty.id=teacher.faculty_id`

query should be like

```
SELECT * 
FROM faculty 
JOIN department ON faculty.id=department.faculty_id
JOIN teacher ON faculty.id=teacher.faculty_id AND teacher.department_id = department.id
JOIN course ON department.id=course.department_id
```

Comment: As you can see, it's not the case. The fact that `faculty` table have one to many relationship with `department` and `teacher` table. But the `course` table have one to many relationship with `department` table and many to one relationship with `teacher` table. That's where it confused me

Comment: @twyla i missed one thing. i edited contents.